# How can I solve this math problem in Uri Online Judge?

Tags: javascript

I need help with this logic math problem in Uri Online Judge site:

[image]
**The submitted code starts in "var n"**, I used the var lines to work with an example of input:

```
var n; 
var j;
var n = parseInt(lines[0]);

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i ++) {
    j = parseInt(lines.shift());
        if (j === 0) {
        console.log("NULL");
    }else if(j % 2 !== 0 && j < 0){
        console.log("ODD NEGATIVE");
    }else if(j % 2 !== 0 && j > 0){
            console.log("ODD POSITIVE");
    }else if(j % 2 === 0 && j  > 0){
            console.log("EVEN POSITIVE");
    }else{
            console.log("EVEN NEGATIVE");
    }
}
```

so, when I submit this: 
[image]
it keeps showing as "Wrong Answer" and I don't know what's wrong

Comment: *the first line indicates the total number of testcases* ... This indicates that the input (`lines`) has more than one line.

Comment: `j = parseInt(lines.shift());` seems not needed. and the instructions said to plan for `0` but your loop starts at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the first line from `lines`. Use `var n = parseInt(lines.shift());` rather than `var n = parseInt(lines[0]);`

```
var n; 
var j;
var n = parseInt(lines.shift());

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i ++) {
    j = parseInt(lines.shift());
        if (j === 0) {
        console.log("NULL");
    }else if(j % 2 !== 0 && j < 0){
        console.log("ODD NEGATIVE");
    }else if(j % 2 !== 0 && j > 0){
            console.log("ODD POSITIVE");
    }else if(j % 2 === 0 && j  > 0){
            console.log("EVEN POSITIVE");
    }else{
            console.log("EVEN NEGATIVE");
    }
}
```